# Whats the main use of item name="types" in magento 2 checkout xml file?

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout

In **checkout_index_index.xml** file,

What's the use of **item name="types"** in checkout page?

Also **item name with form.input** is not defined anywhere in checkout module.

```
<argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="types" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="form.input" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                </item>
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Can anyone let me know whats the use of above xml code in checkout page?

Thanks.